# Multiple lines to text using input in batch

Tags: batch-file

i'm looking for a way to add multiple lines to a text file using a batch file.
i work at a CNC machine and it has 2 directions X(Left(-)/ right) Y(up)/Down(-)
it uses a text file to load in these directions.
there are a few lines that are always placed at th start and the end.

```
These are at the start:

N1 G17 G90
N3 G54
N5 S3000
N7 M03
N9 F2000

This is at the end

N21 M05
N23 M30
```

in between u need to add some lines to make a sort of drawing 
N11 G01 X0 Y0 // the N number is the line it uses, G01 is if its a slow or (G00)fast movement (that stays the same) and then there is X0 Y0 thats the position it starts at.
it always starts with X0 Y0
from there o i would like to be able to ad multiple lines (not knowing how many) by inputting it in a batch program.

something like tis:

```
set /p x="left/right = "
set /p y="up/down = "

N1 G17 G90>> file.txt 
N3 G54>> file.txt
N5 S3000>> file.txt
N7 M03>> file.txt
N9 F2000>> file.txt
N11 G01 X%x% Y%y%>>file.txt
N13 G01 X%x% Y%y%>>file.txt //some more different then the last
N15 G01 X%x% Y%y%>>file.txt //some more different then the last

N21 M05>>file.txt
N23 M30>>file.txt
```

is that possible to do?
if so, can someone try to explain how i can do that?

Comment: Yes, that is possible to do...

Comment: Oke that whas kinda stupid of me..., changed the post, so do you also have a solution to my question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing. You give several details that are not related to the problem, but just make its description confusing. On the other hand, you do *not* give the important details: are the lines always numbered by odd numbers? If so, the example is confusing, because it requires to *always* insert the lines `11 13 15 17 19`, so the lines `N21` and `N23` goes at end. In such a case the lines are five, but then the "add multiple lines (not knowing how many)" phrase is wrong! Are not the final lines always numbered N21 and N23, but with the final numbers? How to specify if the movement is slow (G01) or fast (G00)? When stop to insert lines? Wow... `:/`

Anyway, here it is a kind of possible solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal

(
echo N1 G17 G90
echo N3 G54
echo N5 S3000
echo N7 M03
echo N9 F2000
) > file.txt

cls
set n=9
:nextLine
echo/
choice /C SFE /M "Slow, Fast or End "
if errorlevel 3 goto endLines

if errorlevel 2 (set "g=00") else set "g=01"
set /p x="left/right = "
set /p y="up/down = "
set /A n+=2
>>file.txt echo N%n% G%g% X%x% Y%y%
goto nextLine

:endLines
set /A n21=n+2, n23=n+4
(
echo N%n21% M05
echo N%n23% M30
) >>file.txt

echo/
type file.txt
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing my question, i'm not used to wright in english, but that was exactly wat i needed.
The first 5 lines are lines to start the machine's engine and movement things,
the X,Y are the directions it can move in
and the last 2 lines are to turn evrything off
The "N" is just ment to specify the on what line the machine is,
it goes standerd with +2 so if you want to add a line in between there is still place to add a line manualy :)

thanks for the post this realy helped me out.

Comment: I've tried to run it on an older computer, but thee it doesen't want to work?

any idea's whati can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

For the first line use `echo "line 1">file.txt`
for the rest use `echo "otherlines" >>file.txt`